# Highcharts ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have a problem using Highcharts.

I want to get an array from my php API and treat the results as my datapoints.

Here is the code :

```
$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });
            var chart;
            $('#graph_temperature').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    type: 'area'
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature'
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    color: '#ff851b',
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    data: (function () {
                        var data_graph;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "https://urlhidden.com/ajaxsql.php?f=get_all_temperature",
                            type: "GET",
                            async: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                               data_graph = [].concat(data);
                               $("#debug").html(data_graph);
                            }
                        });
                        return data_graph;                            
                    })()
                }]
            })
        })
    });
```

My array is like :

```
[[1394908920000,20.87], [1394908980000,20.87], [1394909040000,20.87], [1394909100000,20.87], [1394909160000,20.87], [1394909220000,20.87],...]
```

My problem is that Highchart doesnt draw my chart. Axis, title are OK but my area is missing.

In order to debug i used this line :

`$("#debug").html(data_graph);`

And the array is well formed as i can see in my "debug" div.

When i put manually the entire array :
`data:[[1394908920000,20.87], [1394908980000,20.87], [1394909040000,20.87], [1394909100000,20.87], [1394909160000,20.87], [1394909220000,20.87],...],`

 it works well.

Anybody have an idea to help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't test my code but it should work.I hope you'll understand my idea.

```
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });
            var chart;
            params = {
                chart: {
                    zoomType: 'x',
                    type: 'area'
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature'
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    color: '#ff851b',
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }]
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://urlhidden.com/ajaxsql.php?f=get_all_temperature",
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                context:document.body,
                success: function (data) {
                    //data should be converted to json object using  [..]
//remove data variable in this format you should get the data
                    data = [[1394908920000,20.87], [1394908980000,20.87], [1394909040000,20.87]];
                    params.series[0].data = data;
                    $('#graph_temperature').highcharts(params);
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

**Updated**
[image]

Comment: I think i understood your idea but sadly it doesn't works. Here is the result : http://imgur.com/QyWqFSX. On the top you can see the graph which is done by directly inserting the array manually, at the bottom the graph obtained using my or your code

Comment: @user3434194 what did you get?I have just tested my code and it works perfectly.I'll update my code + screen

Comment: i added on my first comment a screenshot of the results i got, it's the same effect if i use my or your code. The graph doesn't render

Comment: @orybon What error do you have?it can be wrong with data from ajax.In ajax success statement I used fake data(for imitation)  data = [[1394908920000,20.87], [1394908980000,20.87], [1394909040000,20.87]];

Comment: Firebug is showing me this error : http://www.highcharts.com/errors/12. But when i don't use Firebug no error shown in Firefox's basic console

Comment: i tried to fake data as you and it's working like this. Then i used my debug div do see what is received in data var, the result is ok : [[1394908920000,20.87], [1394908980000,20.87], [1394909040000,20.87], ... ]. I copy/pasted the whole result to launch a new test with fake data, it's working with the whole result.But still impossible tu use directly the line : params.series[0].data = data;

Comment: i found ! i just added this line : data = JSON.parse(data); and it's now working. Seems that the result of my API wasn't an instance of Array. It's your indications that put me on the way to find the solution, a great thank you Oyeme for your help.